# maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 refuses to show warnings

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I just set up a new project using maven 3. I added the following statement to my code:

```
    if(5==5){

    }
```

Which results in a comparing identical expressions warning in eclipse.

I use the following configuration for the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But it refuses to show the warning.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Xlint` argument you're specifying will cause the javac compiler to warn about unchecked generic operations but, even with the [other -Xlint options](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/javacs-xlint-options.html), there's no way to get the warning you're after from `javac`.
You'll need to configure your build to use the Eclipse compiler. See the Maven documentation for how to [use a non-javac compiler](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/non-javac-compilers.html).